# BCP with Custom column and Row Delimiters

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I need some help with a flatfile a 3rd party is supplying to us that uses:

```
Field1[**]Field2[**]Field3[**]Field4[<>]Field1[**]Field2[**]Field3[**]Field4[<>]
```

as:

```
Row1:Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4
Row2:Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4
```

as a flat file. I want to be able to import the flat file directly to a table via BCP or Openrowset or Bulk Insert with SSMS 17.5

I'm guessing I need a format file, but I haven't got a clue how to define these delimiters! The square brackets are a part of the delimiter.

My only alternative is a CLOB and Replace but that's double handling..

Comment: In a rush, sorry, this may help you : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5345/nonstandard-delimiters-for-columns-and-rows-using-sql-server-bulk-insert/  (bulk insert allows you to specify row and field separators)

Comment: BCP also has options for specifying `row_term` and `field_term`

Comment: You just need to specify the [row and field terminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for bulk insert.

Something like:

    `BULK INSERT YourTable FROM 'C:\someFileLocation\filename.txt'  
       WITH (  
          FIELDTERMINATOR = '[**]',  
          ROWTERMINATOR = '[<>]'  
    ); `. Not sure if BulkInsert will complain about those delimiters though. @MatBailie first post is a good way to handle that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all

Couldn't see the wood for the trees.

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[My Table]
FROM 'F:\Myfile.txt'
WITH (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = '[**]'
     ,ROWTERMINATOR = '[<>]'
     ,FIRSTROW=1
)
```

RESOLVED :)